# How can i fix error on Angular 9 production build with Ivy : "ERROR in The target entry-point "module" has missing dependencies"

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-ivy

When building an application in Angular 9 with the Ivy compiler I get the message:

```
>     ERROR in The target entry-point "device-variables" has missing dependencies:
      - ./lib/pages/variables-list-flat/variables-list-flat.component
      - ./lib/pages/variables-edit-import/variables-edit-import.component       
      - ./lib/components/dialogs/set-base-path-dialog/set-base-path-dialog.component
      - ./lib/pages/variables-edit-import/structure-api.service
      - ./lib/pages/variables-list-flat/variables-list.service
      - ./lib/pages/variables/variables.component
```

This only happens when building in production mode.

These errors come from a library I created that is in the node modules folder.

For each error of the above, another error is printed out. I will just show one example here:

```
>     ERROR in node_modules/device-variables/public-api.d.ts:1:15 
      - error TS2307: Cannot find module './lib/pages/variables-list-flat/variables-list-flat.component'.
      1 export * from './lib/pages/variables-list-flat/variables-list-flat.component';
```

But the Component is definitely there. I can see it in my node modules. In the d.ts file and also the js files.

I'm Lazy loading the module through a wrapper module as shown at the bottom of this githb issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6373[through a wrapper module](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6373)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Breadcrumb } from 'shared-lib';
import { DeviceVariablesModule, VariablesComponent } from 'device-variables';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    DeviceVariablesModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(
        [
            {
                path: '', component: VariablesComponent,
                data: {
                    breadcrumbs: [
                        new Breadcrumb([
                            { lang: 'de', value: 'Variablen' },
                            { lang: 'en', value: 'Measurements' }
                        ], '/measurements', null, true)
                    ]
                },
            }
        ])
   ]
})
export class DeviceVariableBrowserWrapper { }
```

I did try exporting all the files listed in the error output and it still threw the error. My public API in the library looks like this

```
/*
* Public API Surface of device-variables
*/

// COMPONENTS
export * from './lib/pages/variables/variables.component';

// MODULE
export * from './lib/device-variables.module';
```

Does anyone have any experience or any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

or more suggestions info I could provide?

Thanks

Comment: What's in your public-api.ts file? I assume you're exporting all those files in it, and have an NgModule exported as well that declares those components.

Comment: Hey Chris, I Just updated the question with details of the public API. I did try exposing all the files in the library but it still threw the same error. And I have used the same technique on other libraries in the project and only exported two files in a similar way and no error is thrown. I prefer to keep it clean if I can.